# Is there any way to reduce THD for low pass filter?

Tags: filter, harmonics

I got low pass Sallen-Key filter for 8 kHz corner frequency but I still got too high THD for 8 kHz frequency and 10V output amplitude. THD I would like to achieve is less than 0,2% but now I got more than 1,5%. Is there any way to achieve it with my circuit or should I change OP-AMP or filter architecuture? I can't understand why 24 kHz harmonic is so big.

[image: Circuit]

[image: Transient]

[image: FFT]

```
FOURIER COMPONENTS OF TRANSIENT RESPONSE V(OUT)
 DC COMPONENT =   6.574066E-04

 HARMONIC   FREQUENCY    FOURIER    NORMALIZED    PHASE        NORMALIZED
NO         (HZ)     COMPONENT    COMPONENT    (DEG)       PHASE (DEG)

 1     8.000E+03    1.032E+01    1.000E+00   -9.735E+01    0.000E+00
 2     1.600E+04    7.105E-03    6.886E-04    1.269E+02    3.216E+02
 3     2.400E+04    1.606E-01    1.557E-02   -7.253E+01    2.195E+02
 4     3.200E+04    2.824E-03    2.737E-04   -9.972E+01    2.897E+02
 5     4.000E+04    3.967E-02    3.845E-03    5.538E+01    5.421E+02
 6     4.800E+04    1.146E-03    1.111E-04    1.742E+01    6.015E+02
 7     5.600E+04    1.165E-02    1.129E-03    1.609E+02    8.423E+02
 8     6.400E+04    5.094E-04    4.937E-05    1.123E+02    8.910E+02
 9     7.200E+04    4.498E-03    4.359E-04   -1.104E+02    7.657E+02
10     8.000E+04    2.797E-04    2.711E-05   -1.601E+02    8.134E+02

 TOTAL HARMONIC DISTORTION =   1.609872E+00 PERCENT
```

Comment: what is your steptime and what window function are you using for your FFT?

Comment: From a practical standpoint, your choices of R3 and R4 should have made this thing a full blown oscillator. I don't think I trust these simulation results.

Comment: Watch the slew rate of this general purpose device! Try a samller input voltage and see what happens.

Comment: Don'r expect a 741 to give great performance - choose a better op-amp with higher GBP and slew rate. Your output waveform is about 21Vp-p - the ancient 741 probably is at its slew-rate limit.

Comment: Your circuit is correct and works as a lowpass (8 kHz). I did a simulation for an input amplitude of 1 V only. Result: THD=0.04%. Hence, it is a slewing effect. Data book: Large-signal bandwidth is around 10 kHz. Further comment: Increasing the dc voltages does NOT improve the situation.

Comment: What simulator did you use ?

Comment: The same as you (PSpice).

Comment: Yeah, you are right for 1V input I got THD = 0,04%. Thanks for slew rate tip.

Comment: Yes - and in any case, the input of 3V is too large because the output gets clipped for lower frequencies (for +/- 15 volts supply).

Comment: But I still wonder is there any way to achieve THD < 0,2% for 10V output signal with uA741 op-amp? Lets suppose I change architecture to multiple feedback or state variable is it going to change THD?

Comment: Yes - there might be a certain improvement in THD for filter topologies requiring less feedback like MFB. Nevertheless, the best choice is to use another opamp if a 10V output amplitude is required.

Comment: "I still wonder is there any way to achieve THD < 0,2% for 10V output signal with uA741 op-amp?" Sure. Lower the frequency. If you mean at 8 kHz, no. Look at a data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua741.pdf figure 5. See how the maximum swing starts to drop off just about at 7-8 kHz? That means the 741 is running right on the ragged edge of its abilities at 8 kHz, and that means that accuracy and distortion will start to suffer.

Comment: Can you get rid of the gain? These things usually have gain of 1, and the equations change for non-unity gain. Less gain -> less distortion. But you should certainly not use this op-amp, it's an antique.

Comment: I think, the slewing behaviour of the opamp does NOT depend on gain. Instead, the slew rate describes the ability of the device (speed) to change the output voltage. In this context, one must realize that the timely slope of a sinusoidal signal has its maximum at the zero crossing point - and depends on frequency as well as amplitude.